# ViewPager + Fragments Starting new Activities

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

If I have a viewpager where each page is a fragment. And some of those fragments want to start other views / activities do all those requests have to be passed to the parent activity.  So for every page in the view pager all requests to start new activities and all results that need to be passed back to the fragments much go through the one single main activity.  This seems like it would get messy.  Is there a better way of handling this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So for every page in the view pager all requests to start new activities and all results that need to be passed back to the fragments much go through the one single main activity.

Since your `Fragments` live and die with the lifecycle of their parent `Activity`, yes they must use their parent to start and receive results from other `Activities`.

As of API 11, and in the latest support library, you can call these methods from inside your `Fragments` and they will be performed from their parent `Activity` for you.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SomeActivityToStart.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

You can also start an `Activity` for result inside your `Fragments`.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SomeActivityToStart.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

And then override `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` in your `Fragment` to get the result from the parent `Activity`.

> This seems like it would get messy. Is there a better way of handling this?

Since you don't have to manage the communication between parent `Activity` and child `Fragment` yourself, this shouldn't be too messy in my opinion.

Checkout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html for a reference on those methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I didn't know those methods could be called from inside the fragment, that makes my life and code much easier!